# while loop in django

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to use while loop to an multi array which consist of multiple records.but that while loop is not working,
*let say i have an array row as*

```
arr={}
row=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
while arr in row:
    print "sucess"
```

but when this returned arr is empty and also do not print anything , means it does not go inside while loop.

actual array is shown below and i want to perform some actions inside while loop  but as i explained while loop is not working

```
((2L, u'admin', u'admin', u'admin', u'admin@qw.com', u'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$eXj6MA955ZvX$rkgR4UNRozcJZJ/CJWw4OEN9ZIPcDoUwM8uvsjKH8og=', 1, 1, 1, datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 6, 4, 12, 6, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 12, 10, 54, 55, tzinfo=<UTC>)), (3L, u'nej', u'Neeraj', u'Dhiman', u'ndhiman08@gmail.com', u'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$WvkaiQNgwKOR$wbI/mwroDHvtjy8qTB0ftUDLfIA0h2OTMzLybtB3pZU=', 0, 1, 0, datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 5, 8, 52, 32, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 14, 4, 52, 16, tzinfo=<UTC>)), (4L, u'suresh', u's', u'p', u's', u'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$WvkaiQNgwKOR$wbI/mwroDHvtjy8qTB0ftUDLfIA0h2OTMzLybtB3pZU=', 0, 1, 0, datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 24, 6, 40, 23, tzinfo=<UTC>), None))
```

Can someone tell how i can do this.

Comment: Use `for`, not `while`.

Comment: `while arr in row:` this is a `for ` statement syntax

Comment: I have used for loop but that not fit in to my requirements , as that return only last array but i want the array of all records ...... can you tell me how i can do this with while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper format for a while to iterate through an array in python would be:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
i = 0
while i < len(arr):
    print arr[i]
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: as i have shown my actual array in my question , i have counted the number of rows for that array so that i can run while loop as i shown `arr=[]
 i=0
 while i < numrows:
  arr[i] = row[i][1]
  print arr[i],"ssss"
  i=i+1`

but this gives me an error `list index out of range` means arr[i] does not work , thus my dynamic array can't be created , how i can do this ??

Comment: I think the error you are getting is from the `row[i][1]` part. Try `row[i][0]`

Answer (score 3):

```
i = 1
while True:
   if(i == len(row)):
        break;
   else:
       print "Success"
       ++i
```

Comment: Why are you not just using `i == len(row)` as the loop condition?